# How to get parameters that are passed to ScriptManager?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

i'm using ScriptManager to open new windows in the asp.net app.

in the new window i'm getting the parameter by using ClientQueryString.

is there a way to get the parameters in more direct way ?

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "OpenWindow", "window.open('MyNewPage.aspx?Param=" + Myparam + "');", true);

string str = this.ClientQueryString.Substring(6);
```

Comment: Use a `Session`?

Comment: can you expand ? how with session ?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_sessions.asp

Comment: it can work. thank you